# change next combobox by textbox

Tags: c#, combobox, textbox

i create some textbox and combobox by clicking a button with follow code:

```
/////////////////add tbxcode
            TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
            textbox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(448, (35 * count) + 2);
            textbox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 17);
            textbox.Name = "tbxcode_" + (count + 1);
            panel1.Controls.Add(textbox);
            /////////////////add cbxname
            ComboBox combobox = new ComboBox();
            combobox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(303, (35 * count) + 2);
            combobox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(140, 17);
            combobox.Name = "cbxname_" + (count + 1);
            combobox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;


            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            adp.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand();
            adp.SelectCommand.Connection = oleDbConnection1;
            adp.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select * from kala";
            adp.Fill(ds);
            combobox.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            combobox.DisplayMember = "name";
            combobox.ValueMember = "code";

            panel1.Controls.Add(combobox);
```

by changing textbox value i want to change next combobox selected item!
how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

First add OnTextChanged event to the textbox

```
//this when you are adding the textbox
textbox.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;

private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     comboBox.Text = "Wanted Value";
}
```

EDIT:

You should create the both controls in CreateChildControls methods and make them visible false. When you click the button you should see the controls. I will suppose that you create both control on button click which is **wrong**. You can add them in the panel too just make them visible `false` and on click make the visible `true`.

```
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {

    }
```

Comment: @sepehr2121 textbox sorry for the typo :)

Comment: The name 'TextBox_TextChanged' does not exist in the current context